# How to Insert The encrypted data using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate provided the way to insert a record into database via the save() method.
Ex:
User() user = new User(int id, String name);
userDAO.save(user);

which is great.
However I am stuck at this:
I need to execute this query to insert a record to the table user
SQL query: "insert into user values("My name", AES_ENCRYPT("clear_txt", "key"));
Just for example: My table user has two fields: 'name', and 'password'. The password needed to encrypt with some key. AES_ENCRYPT is a function in MySQL.

How do I do this the Hibernate way?
how do you deal with a requirement to encrypt a field in database with provided key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encrypt in Java, before persisting to the database, or you could use a [ColumnTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ColumnTransformer.html)

> Custom SQL expression used to read the value from and write a value to a column. Use for direct object loading/saving as well as queries. The write expression must contain exactly one '?' placeholder for the value. For example: read="decrypt(credit_card_num)" write="encrypt(?)"

Comment: Did you click on the link? What aren't you getting?

Comment: i want to use Mysql aes_encrypt() function..where to write this?

and how can i use read and write ?

Comment: replace `decrypt(credit_card_num)` by `AES_DECRYPT(password, 'key'))`, and `encrypt(?)`by `AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key')`.  I thought the example was close enough to what you were asking...

Comment: i understand this, but in code where to use??
i have  a bean class(setter/getter) without annotations

Comment: public String getInterfaceType() {
  return interfaceType;
 }

 public void setInterfaceType(String interfaceType) {
  this.interfaceType = interfaceType;
 }

 public String getCircle() {
  return circle;
 }
this is my Bean, now where to mention which column has to be encrypted

Comment: i tried in this way, but now working
@Column(name="message")
@ColumnTransformer(
read="AES_ENCRYPT(?,'password')", 
write="AES_DECRYPT(?,'password')")
public String getMessage() {
return message;

}
public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;

Answer (score 0):

How do I do this the Hibernate way? how do you deal with a requirement to encrypt a field in database with provided key?

Hibernate way to work with MySQL:

```
//  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
@Column(name = "username")
@ColumnTransformer(
        read = "cast(aes_decrypt(username, 'yourkey') as char(255))", 
        write = "aes_encrypt(?, 'yourkey')")
private String username;
```

Hibernate will transform the for the username column into sql during get:

Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_6_4_, ..., cast(aes_decrypt(this_.kronologis, 'ABC') as char(1020)) as kronolo11_6_4_,...

during save:

Hibernate: insert into e010_k2_pusdalops.kejadian (...kronologis...) values (..., aes_encrypt(?, 'ABC'),...)

Hope that solves your problem.

Cheers.